Get/Set equipment properties in Plant3d
I'm trying to get and edit the properties values of an natively created equipment in Plant3d . This equipments, by default, comes without the majority of the properties and the others are filled with generic values (like Long Description (Size) as "Heat Exchanger", for example).
I tried to use this code to get this:
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
using Autodesk.ProcessPower.ProjectManager;
using Autodesk.ProcessPower.PlantInstance;
using Autodesk.ProcessPower.DataLinks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Autodesk.ProcessPower.PnP3dObjects;

namespace ParametEquip
{
public class Plugin
{
[CommandMethod("PARAMEQ", CommandFlags.UsePickSet)]
public static void ParametEquip()
{
Document doc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
Database db = doc.Database;
Editor ed = doc.Editor;

            using (Transaction trans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {
                PlantProject projeto = PlantApplication.CurrentProject;
                Project pj = projeto.ProjectParts["PnId"];
                DataLinksManager dlm = pj.DataLinksManager;
    
                BlockTable bt = (BlockTable)trans.GetObject(doc.Database.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
                if (bt != null)
                {
                    BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)trans.GetObject(bt[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace], OpenMode.ForWrite);
                    if (btr != null)
                    {
                        foreach (ObjectId id in btr)
                        { 
                            Entity ent = (Entity)trans.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForWrite);
                            int linha = dlm.FindAcPpRowId(ent.ObjectId);
                            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> props;
                            props = dlm.GetAllProperties(linha, true);
                            foreach (var  prop in props)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show($"Propriedade: {prop.Key} \nValor: {prop.Value}");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                
                
                trans.Commit();
            }
        }
    }

}

But I get this error:
enter image description here
Details:

Application does not support just-in-time (JIT)
debugging. See the end of this message for details.
Exception Text **************
Autodesk.ProcessPower.DataLinks.DLException: ObjectDoesNotHaveLink
at Autodesk.ProcessPower.DataLinks.DLException.ThrowError(_EPpDataLinksStatus stat)
at Autodesk.ProcessPower.DataLinks.DataLinksManager.FindAcPpRowId(ObjectId oid)
at ParametEquip.Plugin.ParametEquip() in A:\11-Temporário\João Castro\Parametrização de Equipamentos\ParamEquip\ParamEquip.cs:line 37

If anyone has an idea about this error or about other ways to achieve this properties, anything will help me a lot. Thanks!

You seem to be trying to find the object in the P&ID database,
Project pj = projeto.ProjectParts["PnId"];

Which is causing the exception ObjectDoesNotHaveLink, which means "I cant find what you are looking for".
To access the 3D data, you must use:
Project pj = projeto.ProjectParts["Piping"];

